# Where to start a multiplayer game for newbies?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I might have to organize a LAN to introduce CK II to a few friends, and for some of them it will be the first game.

When I have to teach to just one I usually have her pick Dublin.

However this time there might be 2-3 new players, plus 1-2 slightly more experienced players, plus me.

I'd like:

- everyone to start as a single-county Count, and to be a Feudal Christian *(also independent, if possible)*.
- newbies to start in a position where it's not too difficult to form its (unformed) Duchy.
- the players will not be fighting each other.
- I'd avoid poor areas such as Scandinavia (I'm not sure about East Europe).
- Better if they are also *somewhat* close, so that they can decide to gangbang common enemies *(this is not strictly necessary)*.

If the newbies end up being only two, I could have them both start in Ireland, and the more experienced ones in Wales or Scotland. I'm not terribly convinced, but it might work.

Otherwise there might be some suitable areas in Spain, France, HRE, Greece?

The Duchies of Susa and Ancona aren't formed in 1066 IIRC, but it's not exactly trivial to conquer them, since there are powerful neighbours…

Anyone has got any clever idea about this?

Comment: A personal favorite of mine is Glamorgan, but it can be a difficult start, but it is noteworthy that deheuberth splits into a civil war soon in, weakening them somewhat temporarily. 2-4 players could be used to vie for control of Ireland, leading to an interesting, competitive game as there are duchies to go round but only one kingdom

Comment: @nickson104 yes, Ireland is a fallback, but I'd rather have them be fully cooperative. Not very easy, I admit…

Comment: Did not see the 'will not fight each other stipulation', how about a start in the lombardy area, a start in ireland, alto-aragon could be worth a whirl too. Wales may or may not be too close to ireland, and is more difficult, but doable. If you want a different dynamic, look for a small power such as brittany/lombardy/france and make them all non-leader counts. Have you asked the players for preferences, this may give you ideas perhaps?

Comment: Also, I dont know if you can play it multiplayer, but you could look at a shattered kingdoms modded game?

Comment: @nickson104 I've found [Broken Kingdoms](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/mod-broken-kingdoms.593646/) and it indeed seems interesting, however I'd rather play vanilla if possible. But I'll consider it :)

Comment: I played a broken kingdoms game last night, and I would advise against it for your ideals. There is a new C.B that you have on all neighbours, which sucks, but so do all AI. This results in most wars multiplying into multiple wars. Also it seems to be that conquered lands pretty much always result in an adventurer, which as you can imagine is hard to deal with, and even once dealt with you are then weak, causing neighbours to dogpile. Definitely go vanilla! I found myself with 3 tribal counties fending off 2 adventurers, a riot and 4 county claims.